# PHP Output error in hosting but working fine on xampp

Tags: php

In xampp my code is working fine but when i uploaded on hosting account it gives empty output json array.i need to get data using t.user_id_sender = '$userdata'.
when i give index.php?user=2 i want to show data in json format where user_id_sender = 2 and all user_id_receiver shows only one time not repeated like
sender id:2
receiver id:2,3,4,5,6
but sender id 2 should not included in receiver
output should be
receiver id:3,4,5,6

```
  <?php

$userdata=$_GET["user"];

$username="root";
$password="";
$host="localhost";
$db_name="chat";
$con=mysqli_connect($host,$username,$password,$db_name);  
$sql="SELECT t.*, p.name FROM nearby t INNER JOIN users p ON          
t.user_id_receiver = p.user_id WHERE t.user_id_sender = '$userdata' group by 
t.user_id_receiver";                              
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$response=array();

   while($row= mysqli_fetch_array($result))

    {
        $cmt = array();
        $cmt["message"] = $row["message"];
        $cmt["created_at"] = $row["created_at"];
        $cmt["message_id"] = $row["message_id"];
        $cmt["name"] = $row["name"];
        $cmt["user_id_sender"] = $row["user_id_sender"];
        $cmt["user_id_receiver"] = $row["user_id_receiver"];


       array_push($response,$cmt);
      }
     echo json_encode($response);
      ?>
```

Comment: Have you tried to rule out all the trivial explanations such as not having the same data in the db on the hosting?

Comment: i need same data in db for other queries

Comment: What version of php is installed on the server?

Comment: @Tayyab first of all check, your connection(you have not, at least in above code). What i think is that you should have a mysql password in your hosting and same mysql data as is in your computer's mysql. and give your php version

Comment: txxxx username issue.my mistake i forgot to change username

Comment: your code is vulnerable to attack .. read about sql injection prevention http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Answer (score 0):

This might be problem with your database connection ,try to debug it, print_r($cmt) at the end of while loop and if no data recevied then correct your database connection.
your code is good and have no issue